Cast columns that might not exist in Polars
I want to cast a column to another type, but there is a possibility that the column does not exist in the df.
import polars as pl
import polars.selectors as cs

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    "viewCount": [100, 200, 300],
    "likeCount": [10, 20, 30],
    "id": [1, 2, 3]
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)

# Columns we want to cast
columns_to_cast = ["viewCount", "likeCount", "favoriteCount", "id", "does_not_exist"]

# Check for existence and cast if the column exists
for col in columns_to_cast:
    if col in df.columns:
        df = df.with_columns(pl.col(col).cast(pl.Float64))

print(df)

Can the be achieved using polars' expression API?

You can use column selectors to select columns by name with pl.selectors.by_name and pass require_all=False.
import polars.selectors as cs

df.with_columns(
    cs.by_name(columns_to_cast, require_all=False).cast(pl.Float64)
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬───────────┬─────┐
│ viewCount ┆ likeCount ┆ id  │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ --- │
│ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64 │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═════╡
│ 100.0     ┆ 10.0      ┆ 1.0 │
│ 200.0     ┆ 20.0      ┆ 2.0 │
│ 300.0     ┆ 30.0      ┆ 3.0 │
└───────────┴───────────┴─────┘


it need not be the same pl.Float64 type for all also, as the columns have to be cast to different types

@apostofes If you want to cast certain columns to different types, you'll need to specify which column are cast to which type. Then, you can apply the setup above multiple times. If you have a dictionary of columns and target types, you can generate the corresponding polars expressions using generator expressions.
